# Jquery - Variables being indexed across the whole dom instead of in each instance

Tags: jquery, this, each

So I have a page im trying to add a flipping section which quickly loops through a list of items - however when I have two independent lists on the page the list items are indexed together as one large list rather than the two smaller lists.

Essentially the variable indexes all of the items in the list instead of running on each of the lists

The jQuery

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery('.flipper').each(function() {

(function flipperexec() {
    var quotes =  jQuery('.flipper').children(".content");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).fadeIn(50).delay(100).fadeOut(50, showNextQuote);
}
showNextQuote();
})();

      });
  </script>
```

An example HTML list 1 and 2

```
<ul class="flipper"><li class="content" style="display: none;">classes</li><li class="content" style="display: none;">coffee</li><li class="content" style="display: inline-block;">taste</li></ul>


<ul class="flipper"><li class="content" style="display: none;">classes</li><li class="content" style="display: none;">coffee</li><li class="content" style="display: inline-block;">taste</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are selecting all the `$('.flipper')` elements inside of the IIFE on each loop:

```
$('.flipper').children(".content");
```

You need to reference the current `.flipper` element that you are iterating over. You could either set the value of `this` outside of the IIFE:

```
$('.flipper').each(function() {
  var self = this;
  (function flipperexec() {
    var quotes = $(self).children(".content");

    // ...
  }());
});
```

or you can get a reference to the element from the parameter passed in the `.each()` loop:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5o6u98jb/)

```
$('.flipper').each(function(i, el) {
  (function flipperexec() {
    var quotes = $(el).children(".content");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
      ++quoteIndex;
      quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).fadeIn(50).delay(100).fadeOut(50, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
  })();
});
```

Comment: You're a star, I will have to figure out what's happening a bit better but I'm using the first solution!